# Copy and replace a file in another directory which does not have the same names

Tags: unix

Below is the case i am facing:
I've a file data.py in a folder and I have to copy it to another directory where i have to copy the file first and replace the file - file.py with the 1st file name i.e. data.py

Sorry if my question is too confusing

Current:

```
/project/data.py

/project1/file.py
```

Expected:

```
/project/data.py

/project1/data.py(file.py has to be replaced with data.py with the contents of data.py)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on [the Unix & Linux SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), or optionally on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. The `cp` command overwrites destination files by default. Is that not working?

Answer (score 0):

Bash does not know you want to replace file.py by data.py.  So you have to issue 2 commands.

```
cd /project/
cp data.py /project1/
rm -f /project1/file.py
```

Better still, make sure the copy worked before removing the file:

```
cd /project/
cp data.py /project1/ && rm -f /project1/file.py
```

`-f` is optional, depends on your system, permissions, ...

---

OR:

```
cd /project1/
cp /project/data.py . && rm -f file.py
```

The general idea is to get data.py into project1, then remove file.py.

---

OR:

```
cd /project1/
cp /project/data.py ./file.py && mv file.py data.py
```

Comment: Just use `mv` instead of `cp`, the `rm` is unnecessary.

Comment: If you do `mv /project/data.py /project1/`, the original file is gone.  And you now have `/project1/data.py` and `/project1/file.py`.  This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: ```
cd project1 
cp /project/data.py . 
```
This will copy the file in current directory 

```
cp /project/data.py file.py 
```
This will copies only the the contents of the data.py. But, I want to replace the filename as well

Comment: Careful, what you are commenting here is not your question.  `cp /project/data.py file.py` will get you `/project/data.py` and `/project/file.py`.  You wanted `/project/data.py` and /project1/data.py`.  Consistency will get you good answers.  Copy the file from `/project/` to `/project1/`, then rename it, or delete `file.py`.

Comment: Ah right ok, I misread your code, and thought you were deleting the original. Still, you don't need the `rm` because `cp` can rename and overwrite by itself. `cp /path/from/fileA /path/to/fileB`

Comment: Please show me how.  Sure `cp` can copy and change the name.  But here, the target is to be the same name as the source.  So the rename has to be done separately.  If he wanted to copy `data.py` into `file.py`, sure cp would work.  But he wants the same name **and** `file.py` to disappear.

Comment: Heh, ok yeah I see where you're coming from. This question is worded really oddly, I dunno how to interpret "file.py has to be replaced with data.py" other than just `cp data.py file.py`.

Comment: No, expected is `/project/data.py` and `/project1/data.py`.  Notice the `1`.

Comment: @Nic3500 : Doah! Removing my comment (and this one after an appropriate time). Good luck to all.